# Install VM from command line with virt-install

Tags: kvm

Disclaimer :

I now use `virt-manager` to create and manage my VM and it is really a life saver. It can be used remotely (from a third machine, typically your workstation) if the host does not have graphical display.

The occurrences of `vnc` in the installation tutorials I found made me think that the "recommended" procedure required X stuff either on host, guest or both. Absolutely not. My mistake. If you are in the same situation, think twice before trying to install the VM from command line.

---

I'm trying to install a Debian VM in a Debian host using `virt-install` and I don't know how to pass it the .iso image.

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --name prod --ram 6144 --disk /srv/vm/prod.qcow,format=qcow2,size=10 --location=/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --network bridge=br0 --os-type linux --os-variant debianwheezy --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'

Starting install...
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                         |  160 B     00:00 ... 
ERROR    Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start prod
otherwise, please restart your installation.
root@versailles:/etc#
```

The solutions I have seen seem quite twisted, like using apache to serve locally the .iso image as if it was from a distant place.

- [Linux Mint 14 : install Ubuntu 12.10 Server within KVM via CLI ( no GUI )](http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.fr/2012/12/linux-mint-14-install-ubuntu-1210.html)
- [[Xen-users] installing a vm with virt-install](http://old-list-archives.xen.org/xen-users/2008-02/msg00325.html) (It is Xen but it looks like it is the same issue anyway.

I can't believe it is that complicated. Is it?

`man virt-install` says:

```
If you want to use those options with CDROM media, you have a few options:

         * Run virt-install as root and do --location ISO

         * Mount the ISO at a local directory, and do --location DIRECTORY

         * Mount the ISO at a local directory, export that directory over local http, and do --location http://localhost/DIRECTORY
```

Isn't this what I'm doing?

Someone says [he moved the .iso to /cdrom and it worked](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688943)  but I didn't understand exactly what he did and I couldn't reproduce.

I cannot use `--cdrom` instead of `--location` as in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/606787/cannot-install-windows-guest-using-virt-install) because `--extra-args` only work if specified with `--location`.

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --name prod --ram 6144 --disk /srv/vm/prod.qcow,format=qcow2,size=10 --cdrom=/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --network bridge=br0 --os-type linux --os-variant debianwheezy --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
ERROR    --extra-args only work if specified with --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media
```

Edit:

Log with `--debug`

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --name prod --ram 6144 --disk /srv/vm/prod.qcow,format=qcow2,size=10 --location=/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --network bridge=br0 --os-type linux --os-variant debianwheezy --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' --debug
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:187) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --name prod --ram 6144 --disk /srv/vm/prod.qcow,format=qcow2,size=10 --location=/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --network bridge=br0 --os-type linux --os-variant debianwheezy --extra-args=console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial --debug
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:195) Requesting libvirt URI qemu:///system
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:199) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (virt-install:193) Requesting virt method 'default', hv type 'kvm'.
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (virt-install:432) Received virt method 'kvm'
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (virt-install:433) Hypervisor name is 'hvm'
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:476) DISPLAY is not set: defaulting to nographics.
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (guest:208) Setting Guest.os_variant to 'debianwheezy'
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (diskbackend:171) Path '/srv/vm' is target for pool 'srv-kvm'. Creating volume 'prod.qcow'.
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (connection:228) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/media/cdrom0/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso'
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (virt-install:551) Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (distroinstaller:417) Using scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:204) Preparing mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:214) mount cmd: ['/bin/mount', '-o', 'ro,loop', '/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso', '/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f']
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:302) Finding distro store for location=/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/.treeinfo
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:325) Prioritizing distro store=<class 'virtinst.urlfetcher.DebianDistro'>
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/current/images/MANIFEST
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/daily/MANIFEST
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/Fedora
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:99) Fetching URI: /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/.disk/info
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:110) Saved file to /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-info.lZMVqL
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                                  |  160 B     00:00 ... 
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1016) Regex didn't match, not a ALT Linux distro
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/current/images/MANIFEST
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/install/netboot/version.info
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/SL
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/directory.yast
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/CentOS
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/VERSION
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/Server
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/Client
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/RedHat
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/images/boot.iso
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/boot/boot.iso
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:183) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f/install/images/boot.iso
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (urlfetcher:225) Cleaning up mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.srz86f
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:234)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 876, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 870, in main
    start_install(guest, continue_inst, options)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 588, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 234, in fail
    logging.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] ERROR (cli:235) Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:237) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 560, in start_install
    dom = guest.start_install(meter=meter, noboot=options.noreboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 384, in start_install
    self._prepare_install(meter, dry)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 277, in _prepare_install
    util.make_scratchdir(self.conn, self.type))
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 201, in prepare
    self._prepare(guest, meter, scratchdir)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 444, in _prepare
    self._prepare_kernel_url(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 347, in _prepare_kernel_url
    store = urlfetcher.getDistroStore(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 346, in getDistroStore
    fetcher.location))
ValueError: Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/jerome/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
[mer., 03 juin 2015 17:46:12 virt-install 12991] DEBUG (cli:248) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start prod
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start prod
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

It works with `--location http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/` but isn't it a bit of a shame to do this when an .iso image is available locally?

- Loss of traceability : you can't reproduce later being sure you get the exact same source.
- Multiplicated use of bandwidth from servers/mirrors.
- Need for internet access.
- Slower.

Comment: You are right, but you can mitigate some of those drawbacks by building a local package cache server using [apt-cacher-ng](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/), or a full mirror using [apt-mirror](http://apt-mirror.github.io/) or [ftpsync](https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror).  Actually CD/DVD/BD distribution is only a tiny subset of the great package collection of Debian, it undesirably spoils its benefits and just irritates us.  Therefore many people tend to maintain their local mirror and enjoy its completeness from the beginning of the install.

Comment: This was fixed in virt-manager 1.4.3 ([commit](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/commit/7fe62cedd5e6492f55effcd4deb23344556e0e02)).

Comment: You might need to use the `kernel=`, `initrd=` suboptions to `--install` if you are using an ISO with non-standard locations for those files.   More detail in the `virt-install` man page.  This is what you would have to do if configuring GRUB to boot off a .iso file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`virt-install` tries to extract kernel and initrd files from the ISO image.  With `--debug` you can see the whole activities of it including loop-mounting, searching for those files, etc.

```
Starting install...
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (Installer:182) scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:184) Preparing mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (OSDistro:65) Attempting to detect distro:
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/.treeinfo
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/Fedora
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/Server
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/Client
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/RedHat
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/CentOS
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/SL
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/directory.yast
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/current/images/MANIFEST
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/daily/MANIFEST
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/current/images/MANIFEST
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/install/netboot/version.info
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/initrd.gz
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (OSDistro:990) Doesn't look like an Ubuntu Distro.
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/VERSION
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/VERSION
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/boot/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/STARTUP/XNLOADER.SYS
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/images/boot.iso
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/boot/boot.iso
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:169) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql/install/images/boot.iso
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] DEBUG (ImageFetcher:205) Cleaning up mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.dwcpql
[Wed, 03 Jun 2015 07:56:40 virt-install 29692] ERROR (cli:445) Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/yaegashi/debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso'
```

I suppose `virt-install` doesn't support Debian netinst ISO images with `--location` (but somehow Ubuntu supported?).

To boot a kernel with `--extra-args`, `virt-install` needs to have those kernel and corresponding initrd files.  `--cdrom` simply attaches ISO to the guest's CD drive, that's insufficient to work with `--extra-args`.

If you want use `--extra-args`, I recommend you to use "netboot" kernel/initrd files by specifying Debian installer URL of your nearest mirror, like  `--location http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/` as described in the manual.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting your answer as it looks like there's no simple way but I think this method has issues (question updated accordingly).

Comment: That will certainly work, but I don't think it answers the question of how to install from a local iso, which you might need to do if you don't have internet access.

Comment: Note that this is not a link to an ISO, it's a link to ... a directory structure known to contain ISOs. Took me a few tries to figure this out. Why this works differently on KVM-Debian than KVM-CentOS (which I just moved from) I have no idea, but this works (still, in 2019).

Answer (score 10):

This method worked for me:

```
virt-install --name=centos \
--memory=8196 --vcpus=2 \
--location=/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso \
--disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=8 \
--network bridge:br0 \
--os-type=linux  \
--nographics \
--extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Comment: This works great with Centos, but it does not work with Debian or Ubuntu ISO files. You will get the same problem as described in the original question. The solution is to specify a URL to the location of an installer --location http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64

Answer (score 2):

The difference is *in the iso files* that are used.

It's not related to the way `virt-install` is used (`--location` used with http URL versus `--location` used with path to a local iso file).

Here's a command that works when using the **Debian online repositories** as `--location` (including getting output to complete the installation until first boot (then two other steps are necessary to finally get into the new VM, but that's another story):

```
virt-install --virt-type kvm --name test8 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-1.qcow2,size=5 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-2.qcow2,size=2 --location http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/ --graphics none --extra-args='console tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

You can take the exact same command, but using the above mentioned **Centos ISO file** as `--location`, and it works as well (except that the connection to the serial console does not seem to work at first, but in principle the installation starts using --location and the ISO file):

```
virt-install --virt-type kvm --name test8 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-1.qcow2,size=5 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-2.qcow2,size=2 --location /softwarestorage/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso --graphics none --extra-args='console tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Output is:

```
Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                | 2.2 kB     00:00 ... 
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                                                                  | 9.8 MB     00:00 ... 
Retrieving file initrd.img...                                                                                                                                                               |  73 MB     00:00 ... 
Creating domain...                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B     00:00     
Connected to domain test8
Escape character is ^]
```

But if you use the **Debian ISO file** for `--location`, you get the error:

```
virt-install --virt-type kvm --name test8 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-1.qcow2,size=5 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test8-2.qcow2,size=2 --location /softwarestorage/debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso --graphics none --extra-args='console tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'

Starting install...
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                     |  150 B     00:00 ... 
ERROR    Could not find an installable distribution at '/softwarestorage/debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start test8
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

IMHO this proves that there's something missing / anything "wrong" with the Debian ISO (not sure at the moment where i got it from, but maybe someone can download a fresh one and repeat the tests...)

Comment: I think you are... very much wrong. In your first example, you're specifying an FTP location, and in your second example, you're specifying a local ISO file.  These two approaches differ because with FTP and HTTP URLs, `virt-install` can "walk" the directory structure looking for `initrd.img` and `kernel.img`.  With a local ISO, `virst-install` must first `mount` the ISO to walk the directory structure, and of course, `mount` requires root access to mount arbitrary (non-`fstab`) locations.

Comment: @DejayClayton: he's right. I've spent all day trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, and Centos 7.1, on a Centos 6 host, using exactly the same mount and export procedure, and `--location` for all 3. The Centos-6 `virt-install` doesn't recognise the Ubuntu directory structure, and `--debug` tells you that. The Centos-7 top level includes a `.treeinfo`, which is one of the things that `virt-install` looks for, so it attempts to boot it. But fails later anyway. I am astonised at what a pile of **** this software is.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, especially if you want to use kickstart files, but here's what I did to get this process going:

```
root@kvm:~# virt-install -n rhce2 -r 2048 --vcpus=1 --os-variant=rhel6 --accelerate -v --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/RHCE2.img,size=100 -l /root/centos6.7.iso -x "ks=./ks1.cfg" --nographics
```

The basic difference between what I did and what you did is that I used the `--location` tag (`-l` for short) to point to my iso.

Comment: This is very much wrong. The difference is that he's installing from debian netinstall iso file and you are installing `RHCE2`.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me installing Debian 10 from an Ubuntu 16.04 host system:

```
cd /usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/
patch <<.
--- urlfetcher.py.orig 2019-07-25 13:54:37.496567791 +1200
+++ urlfetcher.py      2019-07-25 13:54:43.180373257 +1200
@@ -663,6 +663,8 @@
                 ]
     _hvm_paths = [("pxeboot/vmlinuz",
                     "images/pxeboot/initrd.img"),       # Fedora
+                  ("install.amd/vmlinuz",
+                    "install.amd/initrd.gz"),   # Debian
                 ]
     _iso_paths = ["images/boot.iso",                   # RH/Fedora
                    "boot/boot.iso",                     # Suse
.

virt-install ... --location=/srv/software/Debian/debian-10.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8'
```

Answer (score 0):

recently ran into this issue. Simply used a remote installer with --location. I must emphasise that depending on your virsh version, links for remote installers may be outdated in the man page.

I just followed this example and everything ran smoothly: https://www.packet.com/developers/guides/kvm-and-libvirt/

In my case, I changed 'xenial' for 'bionic' in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/ and the installation went through. Going to use this method every time from now on.

Answer (score 0):

When using `--location` you need to include the RAM disk and kernel file.

You can use `isoinfo -J -i file.iso -l | grep '(initrd|vmlinuz)'` to find the corresponding files.

| Distro | Kernel path | RAM disk path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fedora | /isolinux/vmlinuz | /isolinux/initrd.img |
| RHEL5/CentOS5 | /isolinux/vmlinuz | /isolinux/initrd.img |
| openSUSE | /boot/i386/loader/linux | /boot/i386/loader/initrd |
| Mandriva | /i586/isolinux/alt0/vmlinuz | /i586/isolinux/alt0/all.rdz |
| Ubuntu | /casper/vmlinuz | /casper/initrd.gz or /casper/initrd |
| Debian | /install.386/vmlinuz/ | /isolinux/initrd.img |

So the `--location` parameter of virt-install should look like this:

- For Fedora systems: `--location $iso,initrd=live/initrd.img,kernel=pxeboot/vmlinuz`
- For Debian systems: `--location $iso,initrd=install/initrd.gz,kernel=install/vmlinuz`

```
iso=/debian.iso

virt-install \
  --disk path=$iso,device=cdrom \
  --location $iso,initrd=install/initrd.gz,kernel=install/vmlinuz \
```