# remote virt-viewer on the command line?

Tags: ssh, command-line, virtual-machine, kvm, webserver

Do I need to [configure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404510/17056) GRUB and make other alterations, or might there be some [equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/q/977089/45156) to `virt-viewer` which is strictly CLI?

My thinking is that "whatever" `virt-viewer` is doing, through whatever "magic" it achieves that, should, conceivably, be available through the CLI without invoking the GUI.

All it seems to be doing is running a sort of GUI version of a console, or virtual console, of some variety.  When I google how to get a bash type prompt from with `virsh` there's mention of configuring bridge networking, or different, for me, fairly involved procedures.

For my purposes, `virt-viewer` fits the bill -- except that it seemingly requires, or utilizes, the GUI.  For a strictly CLI it gets more involved?

This is in the context of using `SSH` to remotely login to the **host** which is why GUI options, such as how `virt`viewer` seems to work, wouldn't fit.

something perhaps [like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207090/17056):

"It can be used remotely (from a third machine, typically your workstation) if the host does not have graphical display."

but how?

Basically want to chain `virt-viewer` with `ssh` to remotely login to `AWS` ***host*** in order to then use `virt-viewer` remotely.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`virt-viewer --connect qemu+ssh://root@kvm.home.barfoo.org:222/system guest`

Don't forget to let your ssh key on the host, otherwise you could have password issues.

credits to [answer](https://christian.weblog.heimdaheim.de/2013/06/12/virt-viewer-qemussh-to-a-kvm-host-running-ssh-on-a-different-port/):

Comment: You put up an untested answer to your own question?

Comment: Your answer would deserve an up, if you would test and elaborate it.

Comment: `kvm-ok` fails on AWS, so no way to test this at the moment.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405404/17056

Answer (score 1):

virt-viewer is a GUI tool, full stop. It requires a graphical desktop to function.

If you want to access a guest while logged in to the host machine directly, you'll need to connect via a [console port](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Access).

Alternatively, you can run virt-viewer or virt-manager on your local machine and connect remotely via SSH (as in your provided answer). This is best done with key-based authentication as SSH password-auth may result in numerous login prompts from virt-viewer (one for each channel, of which there are several for any given connection [usb/display/cursor/inputs/etc.]).

Note that you do not need to install virt-viewer or virt-manager on the host machine, as these tools communicate directly with libvirt.